# extract URL from .swf file

Tags: image, url, flash, extract

I am trying to extract images from flash on the following web-site: http://meijer.shoplocal.com/meijer/default.aspx?action=entryflash&storeref=120

I noticed that every time I click on "Next image", an images is requested from sever. Sample URL is http://akimages.shoplocal.com/dyn_rppi/740.0.75.0/meijer/large/110206os_o_003_T1C1_2pw26.jpg

So, this URL is exactly what I need, but I don't know how to extract all these URLs from the .swf file I have. I don't have any experience with flash, but I think that URLs should be in the .swf file. I tried "grep '110206os_o_003_T1C1_2pw26' adspage_slider-2.swf", but didn't get any result :(((

Comment: Note that this is most likely against the site's [Terms and Conditions](http://meijer.shoplocal.com/meijer/controls/default/TermsOfUseContent.html#terms). It would be much preferable to get permission from them and using an API or direct URLs provided by them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivan,

Did you try a Flash decoder? It should allow you to access the code and respective resources. Another possible and easier way would be to use Fiddler2 to extract the URLs that you have clicked from the swf file. Still, before you move further, make sure that you're not breaking any of the site's Terms and Conditions.